# Some doubts about request mapping in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am studying for Spring MVC and on the study material I have the following question on which I have some doubts:

> Assuming a web application context name of **"rewardsonline"**, a
>   servlet mapping of **/admin/***, and an incoming URL of
>   "**"rewardsonline/admin/accounts/show"** what is the URL used from
>   Spring MVC request-mapping purpose?
>
> - **/rewardsonline/admin/accounts/show**
> - **/admin/accounts/show**
> - **/accounts/show**
> - **/show**

I think that the correct answer is **/accounts/show** and I have reason in the following way: **rewardsonline** is the applcation name (the **application context name** is the application name**.

Whereas **/admin/accounts/** is the **servlet mapping** and finnaly **show** is the request mapping (mapped on a specific method).

Is it reasoning correct or am I missing something?

Comment: could you provide your complete mapping file. When you say incomming url your mean the url where the request is made ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumptions are correct

given this web.xml fragment

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>your org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

in your classes you must write

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/accounts/show", method = RequestMethod.GET)
...your method starts here
```

to map class methods to single url

remember to put this

```
<context:component-scan base-package="the package of the classes you want to map"/>
```

in your spring configuration

Answer (score 1):

Correct. As you said "rewardsonline" is application context.  /admin/* is servlet mapping which means any request coming from /admin/ will be handled by spring mvc. /accounts/show is used for request mapping purpose. Controller with mapping /accounts/show will handle this request.